# hibernate fetching duplicate records

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Some time back I was having a problem with fetching child entities using inner join.

[Not able to fetch child entities using inner join in spring data jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731114/not-able-to-fetch-child-entities-using-inner-join-in-spring-data-jpa?noredirect=1#comment86476213_49731114)

The problem I am facing now is a little different.

```
@Query("select t1 from Department t1 inner join t1.employee t2 where t1.deptHead = :deptHead and t1.departmentId = :deptId and t2.isActive != 'N')
public Department fetchDepartmentByActiveEmployees(@Param(deptId) Long deptId, @Param(deptHead) String deptHead);
```

Above code is working after using `@Fetch(FetchType.Join)`

```
 @Query("select t1 from Department t1 inner join t1.employee t2 where t1.deptHead = :deptHead and t2.isActive != 'N')
    public List<Department> fetchDepartmentByActiveEmployees(@Param(deptId) Long deptId, @Param(deptHead) String deptHead);
```

When using only deptHead as query parameter, I am getting duplicate records.

One solution I have is use Set for one-many mapping instead of list.

But if I do that, I have to make a lot of code changes which I want to avoid.
Is there any other alternative?

[image]

When I query with dept_head I am supposed to get a list of size two whereas I am getting list of size 8.

Comment: Please add your code to your question

Comment: Try use `DISTINCT`. `@Query("select DISTINCT t1 from Department t1 inner join fetch t1.employee t2 where t1.deptHead = :deptHead and t1.departmentId = :deptId and t2.isActive != 'N')`

Comment: It is available as a part of different question, link to which I have provided in the question.

Comment: Still, please add your code to this question as well.

Comment: if you still face issue, then please add sample data in your question

Answer (score -1):

You are querying on **department** table and there are 4 employee is belongs to that department (dept_head = Ram) , and because of that you are getting duplicate records from department table

```
dept_head  dept_name    employee_name  
---------  -----------  ---------------
Ram        Electrical   X              
Ram        Electrical   Y              
Ram        Electronics  A              
Ram        Electronics  B
```

You can use **distinct clause** before your query to get only unique department.

Even your normal sql query will also return the same thing.
check [Here](http://rextester.com/MHL27339)

```
 @Query("select distinct t1 from Department t1 inner join t1.employee t2 where t1.deptHead = :deptHead and t2.isActive != 'N')
```

as suggested by @hadi j in comment.

Comment: I am expecting 2 records where as distinct will give me just one

Comment: please try demo that i have added in answer, and also try http://rextester.com/HBM57592